# For Loop Should Find if a Value Exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, for-loop, if-statement

For context, the function below takes the parameter "rank" as an uppercase letter (EX: "A"). "#nodeField" is a div.

When the code is run, the code below will interpret the input "rank" and append an "h1" to the "nodeField". Every "h1" has a different id, with the first letter being its rank and the second letter being its position in the rank (see lines 19 and 21). The for-loop at line 8 should test if any "h1" of the next rank exists in the "nodeField" (EX: If the input rank is "A", test if any "h1"s with rank "B" exist). If any "h1" of the next rank does exist, nextNodeRank should equal true (this variable affects the if-statement on line 17).

Does anyone know how to fix the for-loop so that the expected output occurs?

```
var alphabet = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"];
var aI = 0;

function addNode(rank) {
    var kill = false;
    var nextNodeRank = false;

    for (i = 0; i < $("#nodeField>h1").length; i++) {
        if ((kill = false)&&($("#" + alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(rank) + 1] + alphabet[i]).length !== 0)) {
            kill = true;
            nextNodeRank = true;
        }
    }
    
    var newNode = document.createElement("h1");
    newNode.innerHTML = 0;
    if (nextNodeRank == true) {
        aI = 0;
        newNode.id = rank + alphabet[aI];
    } else {
        newNode.id = rank + alphabet[aI];
    }
    
    document.getElementById("nodeField").appendChild(newNode);
    
    aI++;
}
```

Comment: `if((kill = false...`, presumably you meant `==`

Comment: I tried this, and it did not affect the output.

Comment: Please provide more example code, specifically some HTML. Ideally, provide a run-able example using the HTML/JS snippet tool.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work as I am using JQuery in parts of my code. I can't link JQuery to my code from my files to stack overflow.

Comment: You can include the cdn version of jquery tho @TBQTLS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing strictly on your question "test if any `h1` of the next rank exists in the `nodeField`", that could be done without looping using an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
let nextRank = alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(rank) + 1]
nextNodeRank = $(`#nodeField>h1[id^="${nextRank}"]`).length

if (nextNodeRank) {
  // There are elements in the nextRank
}
```

Additional reference for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
function nextRankElements(rank) {
  var alphabet = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];
  let nextRank = alphabet[alphabet.indexOf(rank) + 1]
  nextNodeRank = $(`#nodeField>h1[id^="${nextRank}"]`).length
  console.log(`${nextNodeRank} elements of rank ${nextRank}`);
}

nextRankElements("A");
nextRankElements("B");
nextRankElements("C");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nodeField">
  <h1 id="AA">1st A</h1>
  <h1 id="BA">1st B</h1>
  <h1 id="BB">2nd B</h1>
  <h1 id="CA">1st C</h1>
</div>

<h1 id="CB">This C won't be counted</h1>
```

Comment: This does not work, as the id for all "h1"s in the "nodeField" is two characters long. I cannot extract only the first character from the id of an h1 using the code you wrote. Thank you for your help, though.